# How to align text in center with XNA?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, text, xna, drawtext

I've been trying to make a game, and I wanted to have text centered in the window using DrawString().

Right now it's always aligned in the left side, I know how to center the location of the text, but not how to center it's align.

To visualise the problem I'm having, take a look at the text align here:
http://puu.sh/tMwJJ/2d012b33af.png

Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: Measure the font with `SpriteFont.MeasureString()` after you have that you can divide it with 2.

Comment: I've tried my attempts, but didn't worked out, how should I apply this code?

Comment: Alright, I've found my solution, and thanks to you, I knew where to find it. MeasureString was indeed involved with it, thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh glad you found it. I was trying to give a more detailed information but have worked at other things and didn't had the time. Glad it worked out ;)